# What did the Three-eyed raven say to this character?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the newest episode (S7E4), Bran is being given the Valyrian steel dagger from Littlefinger. Bran is mostly silent this whole time. But he says something to Peter that I couldn't make out, and Peter seems to be stunned (as everyone seems to be nowadays) upon hearing the line in question. I even looked at it again, but what did Bran say and what was its meaning?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Chaos is a ladder

The reason Littlefinger is so stunned is because he says the same to Varys when they had a private meeting in the Throne room in an earlier season. This was Bran's way of showing Littlefinger that he knew he was lying when he said he didn't know who the dagger belonged to.

Here's the clip of when Bran says it to Littlefinger:

This is when Littlefinger says it to Varys:

Comment: I interpreted it as the Bran-eyed-raven-thing saying, "I know even the most secret of meetings you've had in the last severals years, and I know everything else, also", and it's only that the Bran part is so... gone and/or subdued that prevents him from acting out or telling Sansa or Arya about some of the worst things (betrayal of Ned high on the list).

Comment: @ToddWilcox Even if Bran is saying, *"I know even the most secret of meetings you've had in the last severals years, and I know everything else, also"*, LittleFinger may hear that as *"Varys told me about your conversation where you see Chaos as a Ladder."* Littlefinger is probably not assuming "this guy can see into the past", because he may not believe an omniscient person exists. He is probably thinking *"That traitorous eunuch, Varys, betrayed me by blabbing our private conversations."*

Comment: @Richs I agree with Todd here. Littlefinger definitely realised Bran was telling him he knows all his lies. He knows who's dagger it was. He knows who he lied to own the dagger before. Littlefinger is 100% aware that Bran knows everything. His situation becomes even more dire when he realises Arya has been trained as a water dancer. He's surrounded by "freaks" and their Sansa's siblings. He's held at a knife edge

Comment: It comes across to me as Bran being unable to make distinctions between past, present and future, across the continent (world?). He recalled that memory like any other, as though he thought he was there. Littlefinger is probably stunned/confused, trying to figure out how he knows, either via Varys or some other spy.

Comment: @Edlothiad You might be reading more into Bran's words than what Littlefinger would. Which is probably what the scriptwriters want you to do. :-) It certainly adds to the drama and tension for the audience to think Littlefinger worries his lies are exposed, but let's not assume that until we see more evidence. Just because we the audience know Bran is omniscient does not mean Littlefinger does.

Comment: You make a valid point. But I'm going to use your own argument to counter your argument. Your interpretation of the scene is as plausible as mine. We shouldn't assume Littlefinger isn't aware until we have more evidence on the matter :-P The scriptwriters maybe wanted his face to say exactly what you've read it to say, *Varys betrayed me, darn eunuchs*.

Comment: @NickT I think there's an interesting question there. Bran was definitely speaking Littlefinger's line back to him, but was it for the purpose of telling Littlefinger "I know, and now you know that I know" or was it simply Bran regurgitating the first result of the query "Littlefinger AND chaos"

Comment: @heathenJesus If Bran can enter "Littlefinger AND chaos" into a search engine, then no wonder he is the 3 Eyed Raven! That's quite a mystical power since nobody in Westeros has created Google yet!

Comment: Bran's not omniscient, at least not yet.  He specifically says that he can only see in fuzzy pieces and needs to practice more to see better. He might not know what Littlefinger did to Ned, or know who owned the dagger, etc. at this point.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy or he could be, but he can also see the billions of other misanthropic things done across all time and space, and can't really fixate on anything in particular without a concrete anchor.

Comment: @RichS: While you're correct that Littlefinger hasn't explicitly shown to know about Bran's omniscience, there is plenty of reason to believe that he understands it. "Chaos is a ladder" does not directly refer to Littlefinger's statement about it being Tyrion's dagger (which happened in the brothel, not the throne room). Littlefinger is visibly unsettled, and he otherwise tends to meet accusations head on and revels in talking and lying. Also, Bran was beyond the Wall and Varys was in the South, when would they have talked? LF should know about Bran and Varys' wildly different whereabouts.

Comment: @Flater It's not that Varys would tell Bran directly, but that Varys would tell somebody else and word would get back to Winterfell.

Comment: @RichS: That is a very vague comment to be passed along. _Other than confronting Littlefinger_, this piece of information seems unimportant and would easily get lost in communication. There's already hardly a precedent for people _directly_ quoting something if they weren't present to hear the original quote the first time. The show has been relativly faithful to making sure that people who don't hear it themselves don't know what happened to the letter (and therefore can't directly quote what anyone said)

Comment: Last episode, Littlefinger explained his way of looking at ALL the things that could happen and preparing for the worst.  Wouldn't that mean he would have to at least consider that Bran saw through his own powers?

Comment: @eshier: It is a somewhat recurring theme that (most) people do not consider the supernatural as a real possibility. White Walkers, dragons, Melisandre's shadow baby, ... ". When Littlefinger says "all", he means "the realm of possibilities". This inherently excludes "things that Littlefinger considers impossible". He has no reason to believe in the existence of an omniscient being until he has actually met one (or heard about one). Before the talk with Bran, he had never considered it a possibility.